# Mutate a nummrec variable dependent of it´s quantity

Tags: r, dplyr

I have this column in my data frame.

str(a)

```
 $ : int [1:2] 2 2
 $ : int [1:2] 0 3
 $ : int [1:2] 0 0
 $ : int [1:2] 0 0
 $ : int [1:2] 10 9
```

dput (a)

```
list(c(2L, 2L), c(0L, 3L), c(0L, 0L), c(0L, 0L), 10:9)
```

As you can see, every row consists two numbers. I want to create a new variable out of these in a new column.

The conditions are as follows:

- If the first of the two numbers is greater than the second one -> -1
- If the second number is greater than the first one -> +1
- If both numbers are equal -> 0

So the result should look as follows:

```
      a (old variable) b (new variable)
1.    2 2              0    
2.    0 3              1
3.    0 0              0
4.    0 0              0 
5.   10 9             -1
```

I tried the following code but I got an error.

```
a %>% mutate(b = ifelese(sapply(a,'[[',1) == sapply(a,'[[',2), 0, ifelese(sapply(a,'[[',1) > sapply(a,'[[',2), -1, felese(sapply(a,'[[',1) < sapply(a,'[[',2), 1, NA))))

    Error in UseMethod("mutate_") : no applicable method for 'mutate_' applied to an object of class "list"
```

Much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this:

```
sapply(a, function(x) sign(diff(x)))
#[1]  0  1  0  0 -1
```